# How to handle 'subject tree input' field on the case form using EasyRepro?

Tags: easyrepro

The Easyrepro framework wont recognize it as an option set or look up. Inspect element shows the data id = {field Id}.fieldControl-subject-tree-input. Please help if anyone has managed to select any options on this hierarchical field.

Tried using set value but the selenium is unable to identify the element.